# Questions about installing BSD on a *technically* external HDD

Tags: installation, freebsd, bsd

A little bit of background:

1) I have a 160 GB hard drive from a netbook
2) I also have a SATA->USB enclosure that the drive fits in perfectly

Now, I'd like to install some flavor of BSD (probably FreeBSD) onto this hard drive, but my current issue is getting a machine I plug it into to boot in the order of USB -> bootloader -> BSD. I found [a guide](http://cabstand.com/usbflash.html) that may work for the actual installation, but I'm not sure if there are any other caveats I should be aware of.

In short, I want to install BSD on this hard drive and be able to boot to it via my enclosure. Preferably, it's be nice to have an entry in GRUB that will boot to it, but I'm not sure if that's even possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Your bios would have to support booting from USB, and some way of setting USB to have a higher boot priority than internal drives, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Go into the BIOS settings on boot - <kbd>F11</kbd> - and choose boot order. It's easy to install most modern Linux distributions to an external drive using a live CD, but be careful to put Grub on the external drive - not your hard drive - or it's worthless on a computer without Grub.